# How to make two manyToMany relations with the same two entities in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

How I can make two different manyToMany relations in Symfony between the same entities?

If I create it by entity generator, I am getting the error:

In SchemaException.php line 112:

The table with name db.table1_table2' already exists.

Answer (score 2):

The generator doesn't manage the relation table properties. You have to write it on your own and declare the `@JoinTable`.

```
 /**
     * @var OtherEntity[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="OtherEntity")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="this_entity_other_entity",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="this_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="other_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $otherEntities;
```